# JavaScript filter out elements of array that are dividers of one element of an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array.

```
let x = [ 2, 3, 4, 6, 5 ];
```

I want to filter it out to be:

```
let x = [ 2, 3, 5 ];
```

The logic behind it is that 6 is able to divide with 2 and 3. So if any element of an array that is greater and able to divide with any other element of an array (except it self) should be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter array values greater than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772718/how-to-filter-array-values-greater-than-x) and then change the if statement to match the logic you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another approach:

```js
let arr = [2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
arr = arr.reduce((acc, current) => acc.some((previous) => current % previous == 0) ? acc : [...acc, current], []);
console.log(arr) // [2, 3, 5]
```

edit: It seems below approach is better, because it does not use spread operator to append element:

```js
let array = [2, 3, 4, 6, 5];
array = array.filter((current, i, arr) => !arr.slice(0, i).some(previous => current % previous == 0))
console.log(array); // [2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check with the predecessors and filter the array.

```js
const
    values = [2, 3, 4, 6, 5],
    result = values.filter((v, i, a) => !a.slice(0, i).some(w => v % w === 0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through every element, and check for multiples greater than elements in the array. If those are found, they are removed.

```
for (let num of x) {
    for (let i in x) {
        if (x[i] > num && x[i] % num == 0) {
            x.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
}
```